# Where is App.config go after publishing?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-config, settings

Where does the App.config go when I publish a website using Visual Studio. I can't see it in my publish output directory.

I have the App.config created by Visual Studio when I added a web refernce to my class libaray. I want to have a editable App.config so that I don't want to rebuild everytime when I want to switch to another web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your web.config file needs to live in the root directory of the application.  If your application involves multiple virtual directories (i.e. nested virtual directories) then IIS will also read in any web.config files as long as they are in the roots of those virtual directories.

Remember that .NET configuration file schema also allows you to put other configuration files elsewhere and include them into the main configuration file when the application starts so that affords you some more flexibility.

Comment: Yes it is in the Root direcrory

Comment: Not web.config.I am talking abt the App.config which VS generates when i add a web reference to my class library

Comment: Ah I see.  I sounds like you need to merge the app.config that VS generated into your web.config.  Your website won't read the app.config as it stands now - you must merge the contents of the app.config into the web.config.

Comment: Yes that wat i was looking for.I just customized the Proxy class generated by VS to read Webservice name from WEbconfig app settings

Answer (score 4):

When you build your project, the App.Config file is copied to your Debug/Release folder with the name .exe.config. If my project is named UseAppConfig, than the App.Config in my Debug folder is UseAppConfig.exe.config
Open the .config file in your working directory (Debug/Release). Change the values. In the same folder you will see your executbale. Double click on this and you should see the new values.
You are all set. You can identify all those parameters that make sense as runtime parameters, define a meaningful key for each parameter and start using it. You no longer have to build your application every time you want to change the parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

The app.config will not be published, but instead the settings will be read from the web.config file.  So, if you add settings to the app.config file, you should also add them to the web.config file.